# PHP MySQL - Show Select Option as selected If Record exist in another table using JOIN Query

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I was working on a task. In which

- There is a *select* tag in which usersnames are showing from table1. I can choose multiple options.
- & there is a submit button for adding those selected options in another table2 after choosing.

**Working:**

- There are 2 Tables: table1 & table2
- Data is coming from table1 in select option
- I choose multiple options and click on submit.
- those list of options foreign keys will be store in table2 from table1.

But when the page show again all the options that was selected previously should be shown now.

But I am afraid from the multiple queries that should be run. like currently, i am doing in this way.

- I run the following query for showing data from table1 in select option

```
SELECT * FROM table1
```

and in the loop of php i am again checking that with a query that the option of this id from table1 is exist in table2 then show selected for that option. otherwise null.

**My DB Tables**
table1: id, name

table2: id

so if the id from table1 exist in table2 i shown selected else not show selected.

the only issue is i want to safe myself from running multiple queries within the loop and use some JOIN for this purpose. but i have no idea that how can we use if conditions in JOIN query.

Kindly help.

Thanks.

Comment: A simple left join should work there. Select t1.id, t1.username, t2.id from table1 t1 join table2 t2 on t1.id = t2.id. The values from t1 that doesn't exist on t2, will have a column t2.id as null.

Comment: @TiagoSilva is correct. Also, you might want to think about scalability of this method. If your tables are potentially going to hold thousands of rows, then you may want to consider a different method before fully implementing this. Otherwise your app will have performance problems.

Comment: One more remark, remove that *. Unless it is a very specific situation, it should be removed even if it test environment.

Answer (score 0):

You want to use a `LEFT OUTER JOIN`

```
SELECT * 
FROM table1 AS t1  
LEFT OUTER JOIN table2 AS t2 
 ON t1.id = t2.id 
WHERE t2.id IS NOT NULL
```

This basically says.

Return records where the `table1.id = table2.id`. Ignore records that do not exist in `table2` based on `id`

Comment: It does not seem that John Doe wants to discard the lines that are not specified "marked", on the contrary - he needs all of them, but that the selected ones are marked. It would probably be better to do this: `SELECT A.id, A.name, CASE WHEN B.id IS NULL THEN 0 ELSE 1 END as selected FROM Table1 A LEFT JOIN Table2 B on A.id = B.id`. And then just `$out .= '<option value="'.$row['id'].'"'.($row['selected']?' selected="selected"':'').'>'.$row['name'].'</option>';`